# Como guardar valor preguntado con scanner

Tags: java, array

Buenos días estoy trabajando con java para un proyecto de clase y tengo una duda.
Tengo una clase de nombre Modul y otra de clase Alumne.
En la clase Alumne he declarado un atributo Array de tipo Modul:

`ArrayList <Modul> modul = new ArrayList <Modul>();`

debido a que un alumno puedo tener varios módulos.

el caso es que en la mainClass cuando quiero quiero guardar los módulos preguntados con el scanner nose como concretar que es de tipo modul lo que ha de guardar.
Por ejemplo cuando formulamos una pregunta y el atributo a guardar es de tipo String lo guardamos así:
`variable = EjemploScanner.next();`

eso mismo es lo que no se como hacerlo para que en vez de indicarle que el dato a guardar será de tipo modul en cuentas de String o int etc

Comment: Tendrás que construir un objeto de tipo `Modul` con la entrada que tengas y luego añadirlo al array.

Comment: Pero lo que no se es cuando guardo el valor preguntado con scanner en cuentas de ser .next() en caso de que el valor fuese String como sería  para indicarle que es de tipo modul?

Comment: Suponiendo que `EjemploScanner` es de la clase `java.util.Scanner`. Como dice su documentación es un parseador de texto a primitivas. Nunca te va a dar un objeto `Modul` (estaría bien que pudieras qué es para poderte ayudar). Sabrás que esperas un `Modul` porque es lo que le habrás pedido al usuario. `Scanner` sólo te va a decir lo que ha escrito y si le pides un `.nextInt()` lo que hace es parsear la cadena que ha metido el usuario. Por otro lado, cuando dices "en cuentas" no sé que quieres decir, será una forma de hablar tuya, pero no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a generar un objeto dependiendo de lo que ingrese el usuario por teclado te recomiendo que por orden le digas que ingresara

Creas tu clase

```
public class Modul{
    public int numero;
    public String nombre;

    public Modul(int numero, String nombre){
        this.numero = numero;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNumero(){
        return numero;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero){
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Y cuando leas lo que se ingreso por teclado :

```
Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese numero"); 
int numero = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Ingrese nombre"); 
String nombre = input.next();
Modul modul = new Modul(numero, nombre);
ArrayList<Modul> listaModul = new ArrayList<Modul>();
listaModul.add(modul);
```

Java tiene demasiados metodos que validan el tipo de entrada que esta recibiendo y si existen aun más datos.

[Scanner documentación](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm) Esta en ingles pero con el traductor de google se entiende a la perfeccion!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me funcionó a la perfección!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recoger los valores primitivos (creo que no es posible introducir un objeto directamente por Scanner) y luego crear una instancia de esa clase con la palabra reservada `new`.

```
String unStringCualquiera = EjemploScanner.next();
int unIntCualquiera = EjemploScanner.nextInt();
Modul variable = new Modul(unStringCualquiera, unIntCualquiera);
```

En este ejemplo estoy dando por supuesto que `EjemploScanner` es tu variable `Scanner` y que en el constructor de tu clase `Modul` tienes como parámetros un `String` y un `int` para construir la isntancia de tu clase `Modul`.